# 001015 (22023): SQL compilation error: argument 0 to function SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS needs to be constant

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on some Snowflake status reporting and monitoring and I am looking at Snowpipe statuses using the [SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_pipe_status.html) function.

Considering that this is a function I tried using a simple SQL to obtain the status of all the pipes in a given database:

```
with data as 
(select pipe_id,
    pipe_name,
    created,
    last_altered,
    pipe_catalog || '.' || pipe_schema || '.' || pipe_name as fqn
from snowflake.account_usage.pipes)
select pipe_id,pipe_name, created, last_altered, system$pipe_status(fqn)
from data
order by 1,2,3;
```

The problem is that when I execute this query I get:

```
001015 (22023): SQL compilation error:
argument 0 to function SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS needs to be constant, found 'DATA.FQN'
```

I've been trying different approaches but I simply can't figure it out in a simple way. I am considering a JS UDF that loops over the pipes and returns the data but seems overkill to me.
Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The error is given because Snowflake expects a *constant* as input, meaning it should be able to evaluate the input at compile time, otherwise you get that error. Using a UDF is one way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the error but what strikes me is that this system function requires a constant, makes me think that while it is called a function it is not exactly one.